# a string with a content of array to a new array php

Tags: php, arrays, string, function

I have a form in html that will take a huge string separated with white space, comma and a white space afterward, and each item is surrounded with quotation marks like so:

```
$s = '"info1" , "info2"'; //and so on
```

So my question is how would I make a new array variable and set the information in the string to be the information in the array? basically making something like this:

```
$array_ex = array("info1", "info2"); //of course there is going to be
                                     //way more than 2 items
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There's at least one question like that per day on Stack Overflow. See `explode` and the many other questions.

Comment: ok I will, sorry I didn't know exactly what to search for. Thanks

Comment: You can have a look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$s = '"info1" , "info2"' //and so on

$array = explode(",",$s);


print_r($array)
```

Answer (score 0):

explode function is used to generate an array from a string with specific delimited character.

As a solution to your above mentioned problem you need to use explode function for generating an array from a string delimited with commas

e.g

```
        $a=explode(",",$string);
```

For more details about explode function please refer the documentation mentioned in following url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php